# Linux : Remove/Delete .txt files ending with exactly five digits

Tags: linux

- BTW this command worked for me-  rm {path}/*[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].txt
- Is there a shorter way? Because as per need we could extend this to
  delete all .txt files ending with exactly 10 digits.

--We need to delete files having names like abc12345, ac12456, abcd98653 and so on..

Comment: fyi this might have deleted files ending in 5 or more digits.

Comment: I have just checked, the above solution i mentioned is working in Mac bash shell(Deleting files with exactly 5 digits at end). Actually i have installed ubuntu in VM, so i will check on that also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cmd finds and rm's files with the filename pattern [any number of digits].txt in linux:

```
find /path/to/search -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '^.*/[0-9]+\.txt' -exec rm -f {} \;
```

And this one rm's files with exactly 10 digits.

```
find /path/to/search -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '^.*/[0-9]{10}\.txt' -exec rm -f {} \;
```

Try it without the "-exec rm -f {} \;" bit first to see if it matches the correct files to delete

Comment: That doesn't match exactly ten digits, it matches any number.

Comment: Also instead of `-exec rm -f {} \;` you can just use `-delete`.

Comment: @Jasper Hi i am bit newbie to linux commands could you elaborate your answer a bit more..

Comment: The shell command I posted uses find to (a) search files matching the regexp pattern and (b) rm's all files which are found. The number between the curly braces specifies how many digits the filename should hold. Learn more about regular expressions by studying this site: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ which is an excellent resource on this topic.